# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> doesn't take into account property names

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a simple class I want to deserialize a json string into :

```
public class ConnectClientResponse
{
    public bool result { get; set; }
}
```

Call of the Deserialize method :

```
try
{
    var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConnectClientResponse>(jsonString);
}
catch (JsonSerializationException)
{
    // Exception should be thrown
}
```

The issue is when the json string has the same form as the ConnectClientResponse class but the property name is not the same, no exception is thrown.

Is this a normal behaviour ? If so, how can I check if the properties names are the same ?

Exemple of invalid json, the property name doesn't match the ConnectClientResponse "result" property name :

```
{
    "test" : true
}
```

Comment: Of course they have to be the same how else would they map? You can create a custom converter and perform your checks there.

Comment: This is intended behavior, Json.NET will ignore unknown JSON properties.  See [Can you detect if an object you deserialized was missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21030712) if you don't want that.  Alternatively, if you want to make any or all c# properties as required, see [Json.NET require all properties on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29655502).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual problem is not that there's a "similar" property, but that your property isn't mandatory.

If you want certain properties to be mandatory, mark it with the [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute, e.g. `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]`. You can also use the value `Required.AllowNull` instead, if null values should be valid, as long as the property name is there.

Comment: What is the best practice between [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)] and using the MissingMemberHandling ? I tested both of them and they solved my problem.

Comment: @Valsov - they do different, complementary things.  `MissingMemberHandling` throws an exception on an extra, unknown property in the JSON.  `Required = Required.Always` throws an exception in a missing property in the JSON.  In your JSON you have both problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MissingMemberHandling on JsonSerializerSettings to control this behaviour. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MissingMemberHandling.htm

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir.