# Json.NET fail deserialization if unknown property is present but not if known property is missing

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class I want to deserialize into using `Json.NET`:

```
public class Settings {
    public MoreSettings More { get; set; }
}

public class MoreSettings {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want the following examples without unknown properties to successfully deserialize.

1.1

```
{}
```

1.2

```
{
    "MoreSettings": null
}
```

1.3

```
{
    "MoreSettings": {
    }
}
```

1.4

```
{
    "MoreSettings": {
        "Value": 42
    }
}
```

I want the following examples with unknown properties to fail deserialization.

2.1

```
{
    "MoreSetting": null
}
```

2.2

```
{
    "MoreSettings": {
        "Values": 42
    }
}
```

I don't think I can use [MissingMemberHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_MissingMemberHandling.htm) since it will fail on missing values. I only want to fail on unknown values. Alternatives?

Comment: `MissingMemberHandling` does do what you want, see [Can you detect if an object you deserialized was missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21030712/3744182) and https://dotnetfiddle.net/9u8Aa0.  The real problem seems to be that, in `Settings`, you need to rename `More` to `MoreSettings`: `public class Settings {
    public MoreSettings MoreSettings { get; set; }
}`.  because currently neither `"MoreSettings"` nor `"MoreSetting"` exist in `Settings`.

Comment: Conversely if you want to fail on missing values in the JSON you would use `Required.Always`, see [Json.NET require all properties on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29655502/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

You can set `JsonSerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling` to `MissingMemberHandling.Error` to raise an error a property is found in the json, but not in your model. You can even add a handler to `JsonSerializerSettings.Error` to intercept the error.

```
public static void InitializeJsonSerializer()
{
    JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
        Error = ErrorHandler,
    };

    void ErrorHandler(object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ErrorContext.Error.Message.StartsWith("Could not find member "))
        {
            // do something...

            // hide the error
            e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```