# Throwing exception on deserializing type/naming-faulty JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Is it possible to make `JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>()` throw an exception whenever the incoming JSON does not FULLY match specified type's properties' names/types?

It just fills props with default values.

Comment: you can use JSON Schema to validate incoming json and throw exception if it is not matching .  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm

Comment: For missing/extra properties, do [Detect if deserialized object is missing a field with the JsonConvert class in Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21030712/3744182) and [Json.NET require all properties on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29660550/3744182) answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Json.NET Schema at https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema

This is from its home page:

```
JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(@"{
  'type': 'object',
  'properties': {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'roles': {'type': 'array'}
  }
}");

JObject user = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'Arnie Admin',
  'roles': ['Developer', 'Administrator']
}");

bool valid = user.IsValid(schema);
// true
```