# Newtonsoft JsonSerializer: How to make it fail if non-nullable string is null?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I find it difficult to force the deserialize operation to **actually fail** if the data doesn't match exactly what's expected for the output class.

```
class ContainerClass {
   string SomeString { get; set; } // <-- not nullable
}
```

Json file :

```
[
  {
    "SomeString": null, // <-- null
  }
]
```

Deserialize function :

```
using JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file); // <-- the file I got from my controller.

var serializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(); // or new Serializer, whatever
serializer.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;

return serializer.Deserialize<Collection<RegisterImportItem>>(reader);
```

I want the deserialize to fail if the string has a null value.
The code above succeeds silently **and places a null value in the non-nullable field.** The horror!

I'd like to achive that by **configuring** the serializer (as in : I don't want to add **a decorator above the field itself** ).

Long things short: I want **all** non-nullable fields to fail if the value is null, no matter what.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no way of achieving this on all fields at once.
The only way is with decorators on individual fields.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.NET was written well before nullable reference types were a thing. The best way to do this is to use the `JsonProperty` attribute.

Annotate the property with `JsonProperty`

```
[JsonProperty(Required = Required.DisallowNull)]
```

Comment: did you see the sentence "I'd like to achive that by configuring the serializer (as in : I don't want to add a decorator above the field itself )." ? Is  there a way to apply this setting on the whole deserializer instead of each field one by one?

Answer (score -1):

your json is array but you are trying to deserialize object, try this code

```
    var json=@"[
  {
    ""SomeString"": null, // <-- null
    ""JustString"": ""test"" 
  }
]";
    var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ContainerClass[]>(json);
```

and fix the class by adding an accessor

```
public class ContainerClass {
  public  string SomeString { get; set; } 
 public string JustString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. You missed the "Collection" word. It works and the array gets deserialized fine. The array becomes a collection and the fields get populated.

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the answer here : [Json.NET require all properties on deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655502/json-net-require-all-properties-on-deserialization)

```
public class RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        contract.ItemRequired = Required.Always;
        return contract;
    }
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new RequireObjectPropertiesContractResolver() };

var serializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
```

**EDIT: That's NOT the right answer.** Now it forbids *all* the null fields, even the ones that are nullable in the Container class.